# Is there a name for magmas with $[x+y]+[x'+y'] \equiv [x+x']+[y+y']$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, magma

Is there a name for magmas (written additively) satsisfying the following identity? The square brackets have no particular signifance, but will hopefully promote readability in what follows. $$[x+y]+[x'+y'] \equiv [x+x']+[y+y'].$$

*Example.* Any commutative associative magma.

*Motivation*. Let $A$ and $B$ denote magmas (operations $\oplus$ and $+$ respectively) and assume that $B$ satisfies the above identity. Then for any two homomorphisms $f,g : A \rightarrow B,$ we have that $f+g$ is a homomorphism.

*Proof*. Consider fixed but arbitrary homomorphisms $f,g : A \rightarrow B$ and suppose $x,y \in A$. Then the following are equal.

1. $(f+g)(x \oplus y)$
2. $f(x \oplus y) + g(x \oplus y)$
3. $[f(x) + f(y)] + [g(x)+g(y)]$
4. $[f(x)+g(x)]+[f(y)+g(y)]$
5. $(f+g)(x) + (f+g)(y).$

We conclude the following. $$(f+g)(x \oplus y) \equiv (f+g)(x) + (f+g)(y).$$

Comment: Don't have an answer, but this might be of interest: If there were an identity element, say 0, then $x+y=(0+x)+(y+0)=(0+y)+(x+0)=y+x$, so that commutativity is implied.

Comment: @Hayden, nice observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are precisely the commutative magmas in the sense of [commutative algebraic theories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory). They are also known as [**medial magmas**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_magma). That the hom sets are again magmas is actually an equivalent characterization. In the language of Durov's thesis we see that commutative magmas are generalized commutative rings.

Comment: Also: _entropic_ magmas: http://www.ams.org/amsmtgs/2196_abstracts/1083-55-75.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Such a magma is called either [**medial**](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Medial_magma) or [**entropic**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2951v1.pdf).

From lines 1-2 of [this paper](https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~stanovsk/math/diffmod.pdf):

> ... entropic groupoid (“medial” in the terminology of Ježek-Kepka) ...

refers to [Jaroslav Ježek](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=151684) and [Tomáš Kepka](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=171065).

Furthermore, from page 27 of [*An Introduction to Quasigroups and Their Representations* by J.D.H. Smith](https://books.google.it/books?id=NfWlUZSOwSkC):

[image: screenshot]

and, from the bibliography of this latter:

- [53] is I.M.H. Etherington *Non-Associative Arithmetics*, 1949.
- [119] is D.C. Murdoch *Structure of abelian quasigroups*, 1941.
- [133] is J.H. Przytycki, P. Traczyk *Conway algebras and skein equivalences of links*, 1987.
- [166] is J.-P. Soublin, *Étude algébrique de la notion de moyenne*, 1971.
- [168] is S.K. Stein *On the foundations of quasigroups*, 1957.